# Oracle 11g Report Query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oraclereports

here is my Query i just want to get the ITEM_CATEGORY_NAME from my table Pr_bom_line_washings but here is not coming data from this table kindly check my code and highlight what is wrong.

```
SELECT distinct itm.ITEM_CODE P_Code,
       itm.ITEM_DESC P_Desc,
       itm.UOM P_UOM,
       NVL (ssoi.QTY, 0) qty,
       bh.REMARKS,
      (  NVL (bl.QTY, 0)
        * (SELECT NVL (last_grn_rate, 0)
             FROM inv_items
            WHERE item_id = bl.ITEM_ID))
          amount,
       NVL (bl.amount, 0) child_amount,
       IIC.ITEM_CATEGORY_NAME  Mat_Cat,
       DECODE (bl.PURCHASING,  'Y', 'Yes',  'N', 'No') Purchase,
       bl.ITEM_BY_SIZE,
  FROM pr_bom_headers bh,
       pr_bom_lines bl,
       pr_bom_sub_lines bsl,
       sm_Sale_order_items ssoi,
       inv_items itm,
       Pr_bom_line_washings pbw,
       INV_ITEM_CATEGORIES iic
 WHERE     bh.BOM_HEADER_ID = bl.BOM_HEADER_ID
       AND bl.BOM_LINE_ID = bsl.BOM_LINE_ID(+)
       AND bh.ITEM_ID = itm.ITEM_ID
       AND SSOI.SALE_ORDER_ID = BH.SALE_ORDER_ID
       and BH.BOM_HEADER_ID = PBW.BOM_HEADER_ID
       and BL.MATERIAL_CAT = IIC.ITEM_CATEGORY_ID(+)
       and PBW.MATERIAL_CAT = IIC.ITEM_CATEGORY_ID(+)
       and BH.BOM_HEADER_ID= 677
&qr
```

Comment: What's wrong? Who knows. Start from scratch, adding table by table into the FROM clause and see which join (or condition) makes the row you need disappear. Then fix what's wrong.

Comment: @Littlefoot not coming the items against this ID = 677 in report but in table have items against this ID = 677.. what join is wrong and what the new join needs?

Comment: There's nothing I'd like to add to my previous comment, Khuram.

Comment: @Littlefoot ok Respected Sir Thanku

Answer (score 0):

It is too long for comment, and may help to solve your problem. Your query selects ITEM_CATEGORY_NAME from IIC, not from PBW and you say you want it from PBW. Also there is a  comma `,` before select, so query is syntactically incorrect, perhaps typo when posting.

Show only columns which are important for joins, change old-style joins to ansi standard, this way you will clearly see how joins work :

```
select  bh.bom_header_id,
        bl.bom_header_id,
        ssoi.sale_order_id,
        itm.item_id,
        bl.material_cat,
        iic.item_category_id, 
        pbw.material_cat,
        pbw.item_category_name
  from  pr_bom_headers                  bh 
             join pr_bom_lines          bl    on  bl.bom_header_id = bh.bom_header_id 
        left join pr_bom_sub_lines      bsl   on  bsl.bom_line_id = bl.bom_line_id
             join sm_sale_order_items   ssoi  on  ssoi.sale_order_id = bh.sale_order_id
             join inv_items             itm   on  itm.item_id = bh.item_id
        left join inv_item_categories   iic   on  iic.item_category_id = bl.material_cat
        left join pr_bom_line_washings  pbw   on  pbw.material_cat = iic.item_category_id
  where bh.bom_header_id = 677
```

If you have rows with id = 677 in table `bh` and these rows do not appear in above query this means they have no matches in `bl` or `ssoi` or `itm`. If you want them to appear change problematic join to left join.